# Node Express strips out the last forward slash in URL request

Tags: node.js, express

I use express in my nodejs server application. When there's an URL request of "www.myapplication.com/helloword/" coming in, how can I automatically strip out the last forward slash in order to serve "www.myapplication.com/helloword"?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember and was able to test with a dummy app -

```
app.use('/helloword', hellowordRoute);
```

Will serve both `http://www.somehost.com/helloword` and `http://www.somehost.com/helloword/`

Please, provide more details...

Answer (score 0):

By default express treat the route with and without trailing slash like identical route. that means express ignore the trailing slash and treat the route with the trailing slash like their counterparts without a trailing slash. But when you set "strict routing" witch by default is "false" to "true" like this

```
app.set('strict routing', true);
```

They will be treat differently

and you can have different handler like this

```
app.get("/helloword", function(req, res){
    console.log("helloword");
});
app.get("/helloword/", function(req, res){
     console.log("helloword/");
});
```